# 'Remove-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, tdlib

I was following the commands listed here: https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Python to build tdlib for Python on Windows, one of the commands is:

```
Remove-Item build -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This is the result on my computer:

```
'Remove-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can i fix that? Thank you

Comment: Silly question but just to be sure: are running this from a Powershell prompt?

Comment: As @Rno's comment suggests, you're mistakenly running this _PowerShell_ command from `cmd.exe` (the legacy Command Prompt).